Laravel Lighthouse Package 6.42 - Custom Exception Creation and Missing RendersErrorsExtensions.php
i'm using the Laravel Lighthouse package version 6.42 to handle GraphQL operations in my Laravel application. I need to create a custom exception to handle specific error scenarios.From my research, I found that extending the GraphQL\Error\Error class and implementing the GraphQL\Error\ClientAware interface is a common approach. However, I cannot find the RendersErrorsExtensions.php file in the package's src directory. I also tried installing the webonyx/graphql-php package, but it didn't resolve my issue.
